# Ubuntu 22.04 Bluetooth issue with PipeWire

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, pipewire

I am struggling to make my bluetooth handsets (Avantree Torus) producing sound in my fresh new Ubuntu 22.04 installation. I have to say it was somehow working after installation, but it was cracking. I therefore followed the guide [How to install PipeWire on Ubuntu Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-pipewire-on-ubuntu-linux) as many forum comments pointed out to use PipeWire with bluetooth.

I am at the point where I can connect the device and I see it in sound settings. I see many available configurations (like High Fidelity Duple (A2DB Source/Sync, codec FastStream)), but none works.
Even jut testing the device it does not produce any sound or very distorted sound.

Any help is really appreciated. I am available to provide any needed information.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as I finally managed to get it working! well not that is my merit, but it ended up being the driver for this model of RealTek device. This made the trick: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89-BT

I hope it helps other with the same chip.

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:b85b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
```